# WP: Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress

Let say i have 2 page in wordpress, Page A and Page B (please notice this is Pages not Posts).

as default wordpress will use `page.php` as the template for page.

but now i want to make it like this.

Page A will use template `page.php`

and page B will use template `page-new.php`

how i can make that in wordpress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the page template, change its name in the comment

`/*
Template Name: New name
*/`

When editing a page in `wp-admin`, on the right side is a combo named Template. Your template should show up there automatically, you can pick the template on page by page basis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use a page template, simply create a template file for that specific page, you can do this using the ID or the slug of the page.

Copy your **page.php** file and name it either.

a) page-n.php
 *- where **n** is the page's numeric ID*

b) page-name.php
 *- where **name** is the page's name(or slug at least, ie the nice version, lowercase and hypens)*

All this works inline with the WordPress template hierarchy.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

See the image on the above link for a visual representation of how the template hierarchy determines which file to load.